# Where do I find GetProcessImageFileName in VB6?

Tags: vb6, windows-xp

I'm attempting to code up a call to GetProcessImageFileName in a VB6 application, but an getting...

```
Run-time error '453':
    Can't find DLL entry point GetProcessImageFileName in PSAPI.DLL
```

I am given to understand it is to be found in PSAPI.DLL from the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx).

My code looks like...

```
Public Declare Function GetProcessImageFileName Lib "PSAPI.DLL" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
         lpImageName As String, _
         ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Public Sub MySub()
Dim name_length As Long
Dim image_name As String
...fill in process handle...
name_length = GetProcessImageFileName(process_handle, image_name, 1024)
```

Does anyone know what I should be doing here?
I'm running on Windows XP.

**EDIT** As suggested by JosephH, I have changed the code to use `GetProcessImageFileNameA`, thus...

```
Public Declare Function GetProcessImageFileNameA Lib "PSAPI.DLL" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
         lpImageName As String, _
         ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
```

and

```
name_length = GetProcessImageFileNameA(process_handle, image_name, 1024)
```

Doing this (it's the same with the W version) causes the program and the VB6 development environment to crash, so there's another problem hiding in here somewhere.

Comment: Is `image_name` actually 1024 characters long? API functions like this require you to create a string buffer to write into. If you lie to it and say you're passing a 1024 byte string and it's not, things will crash.

Comment: @Deanna, thanks for that: I've just added `image_name = String(1024, " ")` to be on the safe side but it's still crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be either `GetProcessImageFileNameA` or `GetProcessImageFileNameW`. Most Windows API function(except `GetProcAddress`) that accepts string as an argument has two prototypes, one with ANSI (with `A` suffix) and one with unicode (with `W` suffix)

```
Public Declare Function GetProcessImageFileName Lib "PSAPI.DLL" Alias "GetProcessImageFileNameA" _
    (hProcess As Long, _
     ByVal lpImageName As String, _
     nSize As Long) As Long

name_length = GetProcessImageFileNameA(process_handle, image_name, 1024)
```

Comment: In VB6, when passing strings, you ALWAYS want the A version. Using the W version means passing string pointers around instead and changign the declarations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; I've edited the question with the result of trying it.

Comment: @JosephH, That's done it. Thanks a lot (I see I had them the wrong way round).

Comment: Surely the `Declare` should have `ByVal` for `hProcess` **and** for `nSize` and the sample call should use `GetProcessImageFileName` **without** the A?